# jQuery smooth scroll issue, page 'blinks' for one second

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a smooth scroll effect:

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:scrollTarget}, 1000, "swing");
```

It works fine, but when multiple items are pressed, sometimes it flashes the content of the page for one second...You can try on this link: http://teothemes.com/wp/vptest/, click on Services and after that click 10x times on Contact...while you're locked on the contact section, try clicking on Services and you'll see how the Services area shows up for one second, that's not good and I wnat to get rid of that.

Ideally, I'd like the effects to somehow delay in execution..I now have a condition

```
if(parseInt(scrollTarget) !== parseInt(jQuery(window).scrollTop())) {
```

to prevent scrolling to the same area, but if you'll click 5 times on Contact when you're in the Services, ideally it should go to Contact first time and the 2nd time it should fetch the correct scrolltop and scrolltarget after the first execution and not the one when it was clicked.

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `preventDefault()` method does the trick!